# relationship between transition semigroup and first order spatial derivative

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

In my research, all the proof comes down to an estimate of the following term

$$\int_t^{t+h} E|\partial_x P_{t+h-\tau}f(X_\tau)-P_{t+h-\tau}\partial_xf(X_\tau)|^2\,d\tau,\tag{1}$$
where $t>0$ is fixed, $P_t$ is the transition semigroup associated with a time-homogeneous Ito diffusion, i.e., SDE with time-independent Lipschitz coefficients and $\partial_x P_{t+h-\tau}f(X_\tau)$ is interpreted as plugging $X_\tau$ into the function $(\partial_x P_{t+h-\tau}f)(\cdot)$.

By assuming $f$ is a fixed regular enough function, I hope to get an estimate of (1) in terms of $h$. In my opinion, the problem is how to estimate 
$$|\partial_x P_{t+h-\tau}f-P_{t+h-\tau}\partial_xf|\tag{2}.$$

Suppose $X_t$ has a symmetric transition density (for instance, the associated elliptic operator $L$ of $X_t$ is of divergence form), then using the definition of transition semigroup, we can show (2) is always zero, hence (1) is zero.

On the other hand, suppose $L$ is not of divergence form, intuitively, if $f$ is good enough, by strong continuity of semigroup, $P_{t+h-\tau}f\to f$ as $h\to 0$ which could gives us
$$\partial_x P_{t+h-\tau}f\to \partial_x f$$
thus $(1)\to 0$ intuitively.

Are there any works about this topic? Can I possibly get a convergence rate for (1)?

Comment: I think you mean $P_{h} f \to f$ as $h \to 0$.  Also, I think (1) would be easier to read if you write $\partial_x f$ in place of $f_x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one can obtain the required estimate by a straightforward application of [Dynkin's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin%27s_formula).  In particular, Dynkin's formula allows you to expand $\partial_x P_h f(x)$ about $h=0$, $$
\partial_x P_h f(x) = \partial_x f(x) + \int_0^h \partial_x \mathbb{E}_x L f(X_s) ds
$$ where $L$ is the infinitesimal generator of $X$.  You can iterate this formula to obtain a better rate of convergence, meaning reapply it to $Lf(x)$ in place of $f(x)$.

Comment: May you kindly explain more about how to iterate the formula? Do you mean expanding the integrand $\partial_x P_sLf$ by the same formula? Why do I need to interchange $P_s$ and $L$ as you suggested?

Comment: I edited my answer according to your feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will think about your answer and accept it if I can solve my problem following your suggestion. Thank you for your help.